# PI and multiple IR emitters

Tags: wifi, remote, lirc

just another N00b trying to approach the PI world!

I would like to remotely control over wi-fi three identical set top boxes (sat receivers).

I don't mind studying how to do it, but first I would like to make sure that is doable first!

I suppose I'd need three wired IR emitters to attach to the STBs (they are stacked together in a cabinet, an IR blaster will trigger all three receivers). 
I also heard about LIRC as a commanding software. 
Would I be able to control the 3 STBs independently?
What hardware would I require?

Thank you and sorry for the banality of my question!

Comment: It is "doable" with some persistence and research. If you use the LIRC software package and the IR shield made by LinkSprite, be sure and [read this.](https://gist.github.com/prasanthj/c15a5298eb682bde34961c322c95378b)

Comment: LIRC is feature rich.  And putting everything into one computer (a RPi can do so much more then just relay IR codes) has advantages.  But if all the commands you need can fit into an esp8266, consider making 3 (one for each set top box) and controlling each independently simply by sending commands using different IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I need basic controls (change channels, on & off, enable subtitles maybe) but I'd prefer the single device option (I have limitations on the numbers of IP addresses I can use). As I said, I would need to attach the IR emitters to the receivers, do you know any suitable IR wired emitter that would work? Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can control 3 STB;s with just one IR emitter (as long as all three have different IR commands). You can use LIRC and a IR receiver to first record the commands sent by the remotes of each STB and then use a python code to send the commands via an IR emitter.

Re. hardware you can use something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0713SK7RJ) which has both an IR emitter and receiver and should make it easier to connect.

Re. the software, I have used [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Useemulate-remotes-with-Arduino-and-Raspber/) and [this](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/) examples which worked well for me.

Comment: Thank you Karan! I think i will still need 3 emitters, because my 3 STBs are identical (sorry, I forgot to mention that before). And, due to physical space limitations, I would prefer to have them wired and attach in front of the STBs. Do you think I can have one IR receiver on the RPi (to make LIRC learn the commands) and 3 IR emitters to the STBs? Will I be able to individually control them? Thank you for your precious suggestions!

Comment: yes, that should work too. Though I have not tested it. In one of the steps, you define the pin, so in this case I think what might work for you is to define 3 interfaces for the 3 emitter, and use one interface for the receiver to record the commands and use each of those separate interfaces to control each STB

Comment: Thanks again, I will give it a try, I hope to come back with positive news!